# What does the "over" joint and what does "look down" mean here?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does the "over" joint and what does "look down" mean here?

> The weather in Beijing is less polluted than it was 10 years ago
>   before the opening ceremony of the Olympic Games, but the boiling hot
>   city **over which** the stormy August clouds **look down** has been
>   transformed in the 10 years since that spectacular event.
>
> Source: [*The Irish Times*](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/world/asia-pacific/beijing-a-city-transformed-a-decade-after-landmark-olympics-1.3588996)

1. over which. I know it's a clause and takes the preposition to the front.
   It means "... clouds over the city"?
2. What does "look down" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes
2. "look down" is in this case an example of **personification**, where an inanimate object is given human qualities or abilities.

> The stormy August clouds look down on the city.

or

> The steeples of this incredible basilica watch over the Wisconsin
>   country side as they stand tall from a prestigious place on top of one
>   of the highest points in the area.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to understand the sentence,

> but the boiling hot city - stormy August clouds **look down over** it (the city) -
>   has been transformed in the 10 years since that spectacular event.

All make sense.